# count number of times values appear in a column

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a database and am writing a django queryset to loop over a column like below

```
distinct_event_identifier=Plasoevt.objects.values('source_name')
```

one source_name can appear more than once in the column.so i want a query to print each unique source_name and the number of times it appears in the column.
I want it printed it in this format:

```
{ source_name: 'MCUpdate', frequency: 30 },//where frequency is the number of times a particular source_name appears in the column
     { source_name: 'LoadPerf', frequency: 30},
     { source_name: 'WinMgmt', frequency: 30 },
```

can anyone give an insight please?
Regards

Comment: Note, if you're playing with my answer, I just changed counts to event_counts, to emphasize semantic naming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations):

```
distinct_event_identifier=Plasoevt.objects.values('source_name').annotate(frequency = Count('source_name'))
```

Comment: Hi Łukasz Staniszewski, i get an error global name Count not defined

Comment: Sorry! you need to import it: from django.db.models import Count

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the counter in collections and using contextual semantics to present this data. (The Counter is a dict subclass available in Python 2.7 onwards)

```
import collections
```

Create our column of data, which will be 90 items long, (and I'll shuffle it randomly since that would likely simulate your data):

```
import random
event_column = ((['MCUpdate'] * 30) + # This is a list of events that 
                (['LoadPerf'] * 30) + # will be passed to the Counter
                (['WinMgmt'] * 30))
random.shuffle(event_column)
print('length of the column is ' + str(len(event_column))) # i.e. 90
print('first 10 items are:')
print(event_column[:10])
```

which prints:

```
['WinMgmt', 'MCUpdate', 'LoadPerf', 'LoadPerf', 'WinMgmt', 
 'MCUpdate', 'WinMgmt', 'MCUpdate', 'MCUpdate', 'MCUpdate']
```

And then we count their frequency:

```
event_counts = collections.Counter(event_column)
import pprint
pprint.pprint(event_counts)
```

Prints out:

```
Counter({'MCUpdate': 30, 'LoadPerf': 30, 'WinMgmt': 30})
```

And

```
for event, count in event_counts.items(): # use iteritems() in Python 2
    print('{event}: {count}'.format(event=event, count=count))
```

prints

```
MCUpdate: 30
LoadPerf: 30
WinMgmt: 30
```

To put it in your desired format:

```
redundant_counts = []
for source_name, frequency in event_counts.items():
    redundant_counts.append({'source_name': source_name, 'frequency': frequency})
print(redundant_counts)
```

prints:

```
[{'source_name': 'WinMgmt', 'frequency': 30}, {'source_name': 'MCUpdate', 'frequency': 30}, {'source_name': 'LoadPerf', 'frequency': 30}]
```

Comment: Hi Aaron Hal,thanks for your answer..but the frequency is a calculated field!!! Is there a way to loop all over the column to count the number of times the source_name appears and append it to where you have 30? thanks

Comment: Hi Aaron,I get an error 'unhashable type dict' when trying to print counter!!

Comment: and from your code sample can you make it print Counter('source_name:'MCUpdate',frequency: 30, source_name:'LoadPerf',frequency: 30, source_name:'WinMgmt'frequency: 30})

Comment: For some reason, you're probably putting a dict into the key, which doesn't work in python. Ensure that the column you want to count the frequency on is a list before you pass it to the counter, then the code should do exactly what you wanted..